# Программа в трее без окна (WinAPI, C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно создать приложение, которое не будет иметь ни видимого окна, ни иконки на панели задач, и работать только из трея.
Подскажите пожалуйста последовательность действий, а так же с какими параметрами нужно регистрировать `WNDCLASSEX` и использовать `CreateWindow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если видимого окна нет, имеет смысл создать *[Message-Only Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only)*, окно без графического представления, предназначенное исключительно для обработки оконных сообщений:

```
const HWND g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    /* dwExStyle    */ 0,
    /* lpClassName  */ szClassName,
    /* lpWindowName */ NULL,
    /* dwStyle      */ 0,
    /* x, y, w, h   */ 0, 0, 0, 0,
    /* hWndParent   */ HWND_MESSAGE,
    /* hMenu        */ NULL,
    /* hInstance    */ g_hInst,
    /* lpParam      */ NULL
);
```

Затем обычным порядком создаёте значок в панели уведомлений:

```
#define WM_USER_SHELLICON (WM_USER + 1)

NOTIFYICONDATA data;
data.cbSize = sizeof(data);
data.hWnd = g_hWnd;
data.uID = 1;          // Можно поставить любой идентификатор, всё равно иконка только одна
data.uFlags = NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP;
data.uCallbackMessage = WM_USER_SHELLICON;
data.hIcon = LoadIcon(...);
data.szTip = TEXT(...);  // Или LoadResourceString, как вариант
data.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION;

Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &data);
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ! Но при Message-Only Window ведь можно будет реализовать меню по клику на иконке в трее?

Comment: @Iceman, да, [`TrackPopupMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648002(v=vs.85).aspx)  не требует, чтобы указанный `hWnd` был UI окном.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Только вот что-то иконка не становится: TrayData.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAINICON)); - пусто

Comment: @Iceman, первым аргументом `LoadIcon` должен быть `hInstance`  *вашей программы* (полученный через `WinMain` либо `GetModuleHandle`). При передаче `NULL` эта функция ищет иконки в системных ресурсах.

Comment: Ага, есть контакт. Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как-то раз делал такую. Не скажу, что правильно :), но работало. Вот основной цикл:

```
g_hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

char * szClassName = "EmptyWindow";
WNDCLASSEX wcex    = {sizeof(wcex)};
wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
wcex.hInstance     = g_hInst;
wcex.lpszClassName = szClassName;
RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

if (g_hWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, g_hInst, NULL));
{
    ShowWindow(g_hWnd,SW_HIDE);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Ну а треевскую иконку создавал в `WM_CREATE`.

Не знаю, насколько это идеологически верно, но работало :)